# Eagle via diameter discrepancy

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, via

I made a part in eagle with vias using a set diameter (smaller then auto), but when I use the part on a board, the vias go back to having a diameter of auto. any ideas?

[image]

The left window shows the board view of the vias and the right shows the library view of the same vias.

EDIT: ok I can change the via pad sizes by changing Restring Pad values in Design Rules, but it changes it for all components ignoring what I set up in the library. This causes all pads for all parts to become thin, instead of just for the ones I need.

Comment: Perhaps forced by the rules settings you have in effect for the board?

Answer (score 1):

You are letting the DRC settings override the diameter.  Use the "as defined in library" (or something like that, can't remember the exact name) setting.  That's what it's for.

Comment: I only see the option for "as defined in library" for Pads. just to be clear, these options would be in the DRC settings right?

Comment: I believe it is called "restring"

Comment: I see it now, thanks. It seems that it changes all pad sizes instead of just the ones I set in the library. Is there any way to set minimums and maximums without actually setting the % size itself, and keep it 'as in library'?