# Eagle 6 : Problem Importing Custom Parts

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, eaglecad

Recently started working on a new PCB board for a dev kit. I ran in an issue where I had made a custom part for the M50-3501042 2x10 male header with 0.05'' (1.27mm) pitch.

Note also that this is a through-hole component.

The issue I had was that I set the diameter of each of the pins in the custom package to 0.04'', however, when I imported the part into my PCB design, the pins on the board had increased in diameter and were overlapping with other pins giving DRC errors.

I updated the library and all the parts in Eagle, however, this did not fix my issue.

I have no idea on how to fix this issue. Any ideas?

EDIT: Okay so I tried the solution posted in the comment, however it did not work for me. Only the via holes on the board changed and not the pins on the custom part. I tried messing with some other DRC settings but haven't been able to come out with a solution yet.

Comment: I tried that however it only changes all the via sizes on the board. The header remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through help files and forums, I finally came out with the solution to my problem (with the help of many online contributors of course). The solution, as expected, has to do with the rest ring that eagle sets.

Initially the rest ring was set at a min value of 10 mil for my DRC file. I lowered the value of that to 6 mil to avoid overlap on the header.

NOTE ON THIS: BE CAREFUL WHEN SETTING MIN HERE BECAUSE EAGLE SETS THE MIN FOR THE WHOLE BOARD, SO OTHER COMPONENTS WILL ALSO BE AFFECTED. FOR MY CASE, EVERYTHING CHECKED OUT GOOD, BUT TAKE CARE IF YOU USE THIS SOLUTION.

I think it would be more convenient if you could individually set the rest ring size for specific components since you have components of different sizes on the board, however, I don't know if eagle has such capability. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Anyways, hope this helps someone else out there. I spent quite a bit of time trying to find a better solution than just modifying the rest ring size for the board, however, I wasn't able to find anything else.

Also, for those who didn't read the comments on this question, here is another resource for anyone who has stumbled here with a problem with Via diameters: [VIA DIAMETER PROBLEM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58733/eagle-via-diameter-discrepancy)

To add to the solutions. I re-posted this question one element14 community forums for Eagle. [Here](http://www.element14.com/community/thread/22547) is the response I got.